# Rebate Program Payout Periods

Tags: rest-api, api

I am trying to create Rebate Program Payout Periods with the following REST API:

[Rebate Program Payout Periods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.rebates_api_devguide.meta/rebates_api_devguide/rebate_actions_generate_rebate_payout_periods.htm)

Following are the permission set assigned to me:
[image]

**Endpoint**: /services/data/v51.0/actions/standard/generateRebatePayoutPeriods

**Request**:

```
{"RebateProgramId":"0i83L000000000fQAA"}
```

**Response**:

```
[ {
  "message" : "Unrecognized field \"RebateProgramId\" at [line:1, column:21]",
  "errorCode" : "JSON_PARSER_ERROR"
} ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We raised a support case with Salesforce and they said it is an issue with the request body structure. The request body should be as:

```
{
    "inputs": [
        {
            "rebateProgramId": "0i83L000000000f"
        }
    ]
}
```